# Not able to install pdo_mysql

Tags: command-line, server, php, postgresql

I m using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. After successful installation of php7.2-pgsql, I cant install pdo_pgsql. I have tried following command:

```
sudo apt-get install pdo_pgsql
```

and got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package pdo_pgsql
```

I update php.ini file as well removing comment extension for pdo_pgsql but i m still facing "Unable to locate package pdo_pgsql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [files provided by `php-7.2-pgsql`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/arm64/php7.2-pgsql/filelist), you will see that the `pdo_pgsql` is **part** of the `php7.2-pgsql`-package.

`pdo_pgsql` is a php module. You enable php-modules by adding them to the php.ini, as you seems to have done from what you write.

In general: if you can add a module to php.ini, and not get exceptions when using PHP, then the module is present.

`pdo_pgsql` is ***not*** a stand-alone package you can install with `apt`.

Comment: Thank you so much. As you said, pdo_pgsql is not a stand-alone package. I went through documentation and i m cleared. Previously, I enabled pdo_pgsql in php.ini, only thing left was to restart apache. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```bash
sudo apt-get install php-pgsql
```